# Implemet ws-securitypolicy with php \SoapClient

Tags: php, soap-client, ws-security

I'm trying to make a soap request using PHP Soap Client class, like this:

```
    $options = array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 
        'local_cert' => 'path/to/certfile.pem',
        'passphrase' => 'mypassphrase'
    );

    $client = new \SoapClient(
        'https:/url?wsdl',
        $options
    );

    $response = $client->__soapCall('get-operation', array());

    var_dump($response);
```

and I get the following error:

```
These policy alternatives can not be satisfied:
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedParts: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body not SIGNED
```

From what I understood I have to add ws-securitypolicy to my SOAP client, but I don't know how to do this.

Here is the XML regarding the security policy:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SignatureRequired">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToInitiator">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:TripleDes/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.test." name="correlation-header"/>
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

My question is: do you have an example on how can I implement the ws-security policy in PHP or a certain library you used?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this implementation of WSSE (Web Service Security) headers in native PHP SOAP.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#97273

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I know that there is a framework for doing that called WSO WSF. But i wouldn't use it because it's latest commit is a few years ago. And because I'm to stupid to bring it to work.
When I try to get a connection the Terminal says:

> No Header Element in msg

So a header is needed. I think that could help you as well. Good luck.